# Incorrect syntax near COLUMN in ADD COLUMN query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE Directors

ADD COLUMN NetWorth DECIMAL (15,2) NOT NULL AFTER DirectorName
```

I have looked up how to do this simple query online and my syntax looks the exact same as online examples yet I still get this error.

[Screenshot of the whole query plus error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQ4o.png)

Incorrect syntax near COLUMN. Everywhere I look online has the query written as I do. Would appreciate any sharp eyes that can spot the problem.

Comment: You are not using MySQL.

Comment: Remove ```COLUMN```

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this?\

Comment: When looking for code examples make sure the example is for the same DBMS you are using. Using MySQL syntax in sql server is like using c# in your vb.net code base. They are similar but not syntactically the same.

Answer (score 1):

remove `COLUMN`:

```
alter table Directors add NetWorth ...
```

And remove `AFTER DirectorName`

Answer (score 0):

In mySQL it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE Directors

ADD COLUMN NetWorth DECIMAL (15,2) AFTER DirectorName
```

See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/

In SQL Server

```
ALTER TABLE Directors

ADD NetWorth DECIMAL (15,2) NOT NULL
```

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like SQL Server.